# Show Full Stack Trace on PHP Command Line

Tags: php, debugging, php-5.3

**Problem**

My PHP Stack Trace is abbreviated:

```
Stack trace:
#0 /www/html/table/app/create.php(128): SoapClient->__call('call', Array)
#1 /www/html/table/app/create.php(128): SoapClient->call('5e81ad4c12668ec...', 'table.ad...', Array)
```

**Expected Outcome**

I want to see the part that is hidden by the **...** when running php from the command line. How do I make php show the full message?

Comment: It's 2024 and it's still unclear to me why as default the stack trace is truncated and we are not aware of any global option to avoid this - that seems quite necessary. Thanks again for the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can surround it in a `try ... catch` and then do a `var_dump` on the exception.

```
try {

    // the code that throws an exception
} catch ( Exception $e ) {

   var_dump( $e->getTrace() );
}
```

Comment: Isn't there any global option to never truncate the stack trace?