# How to see the full stack trace in PHP?

Tags: php, pdo, stack-trace

I am running a script using Eloquent in standalone from the command line. I have an error somewhere in a SQL query, but the stack trace I get is incomplete:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: 
    Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' 
    in 'where clause' in ./vendor/illuminate/database/Connection.php:326
Stack trace:
#0 ./vendor/illuminate/database/Connection.php(326): 
    PDO->prepare('select * from `...')
#1 ./vendor/illuminate/database/Connection.php(657): 
    Illuminate\Database\Connection->Illuminate\Database\{closure}('select * from `...', Array)
#2 ./vendor/illuminate/database/Connection.php(624): 
    Illuminate\Database\Connection->runQueryCallback('select * from `...', Array, Object(Closure))
#3 ./vendor/illuminate/database/Connection.php(333): 
    Illuminate\Database\Connection->run('select * from `...', Array, Object(Closure))
#4 ./vendor/illuminate/database/Query/Builder.php(2062): 
    Illuminate\Database\Connection->select('select * from `...', Array, true)
#5 ./vendor/illuminate/database/Query/Builder.php(2050): 
    Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder->runSelect()
#6 /srv/nes in ./vendor/illuminate/database/Connection.php on line 664
```

How can I get the full stack-trace with no `...` in my SQL queries?

Comment: The error is that you are trying to query a column `id` that doesn't exist in the table

Comment: I know thanks :) But do you know which table of which schema?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show Full Stack Trace on PHP Command Line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34498002/show-full-stack-trace-on-php-command-line)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try to adding these;

```
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
```